# SAS datetime formatting as POSIX

Tags: datetime, posix, sas

I want SAS to format datetimes in a POSIX format. The following gives "2009-11-25 14:44:56" how can I display the milliseconds ?

```
proc format;
    picture POSIX other='%0Y-%0m-%0d %0H:%0M:%0S' (datatype=datetime);
run;
data test;
  mydatetime='25nov2009 14:44:56.300'dt;
  format newdt POSIX.;
  newdt=mydatetime;
  put mydatetime= newdt=;
run;
```

EDIT : I am even taker of ANY way to format datetimes to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:M:SS.sss` (ISO8601) amazing I can't find this in less than 1 minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E8601DT23.3 should display your values as you wish, except for the extra "T" separator; SAS seems to require that.  If you're putting to a character value you can remove the "T" easily; if you are trying to use a formatted numeric value, I think you would have to live with it.

```
data test;
  mydatetime='25nov2009 14:44:56.356'dt;
  format newdt E8601DT23.3;
  newdt=mydatetime;
  put mydatetime= newdt=;
run;
```

SAS guide on ISO8601:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm

Edit:  SAS-L came through on this one ( http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A1=ind1303c&L=sas-l#8 ).  If you have 9.3 this should work (not in 9.2 or earlier).

```
proc format;
    picture POSIX other='%0Y-%0m-%0d %0H:%0M:%0s' (datatype=datetime);
run;
data test;
  mydatetime='25nov2009 14:44:56.300'dt;
  format newdt POSIX23.3;
  newdt=mydatetime;
  put mydatetime= newdt=;
run;
```

Little s, and include the decimal, and it should work as expected.  Thanks to data *null* for the tip.

Comment: Thanks, Joe I finally found this too. I still cannot find anyway to define my own format handling milliseconds...

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to be possible for some reason - sorry!

Comment: Edited to include an update for version 9.3, which does handle milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only works for values of second from 10-59. It does not work for values of second 0-9. There is no leading zero for values of second 0-9.